# Laravel Inertia wrong redirect header location for 303 status code

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I am using laravel mix with browserSync for development server, my laravel server is localhost:8000 and browserSync server is localhost:3000.

```php
  public function update(User $user, ClientePFRequest $request)
  {
    ...

    // this has localhost:3000 location header
    return redirect(
      "http://localhost:3000" . route("admin.clientes.pf.show", $user, false)
    )->with("success", "Cliente Pessoa Física atualizado com sucesso");

    // this has localhost:3000 route, but responds with localhost:8000 location header
    return redirect()
      ->route("admin.clientes.pf.show", $user)
      ->with("success", "Cliente Pessoa Física atualizado com sucesso");
  }
```

Inertia requires and sets the status code as 303 for PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods under the hood.

With POST method it works as intended, it has a localhost:3000 location header with 302 status code, but for PUT method, since it changes for 303 status code it gets wrong location header response.

If I explicitly set the redirect route with localhost:3000, it works, but if I don't, even though the response object sets localhost:3000, it turns into localhost:8000 for some reason that I can't figure out.

Edit:

I found one way to solve it programmatically.

```php
  public function update(User $user, ClientePFRequest $request)
  {
    ...

    return redirect(
      $request->server->get("HTTP_ORIGIN") .
        route("admin.clientes.pf.show", $user, false)
    )->with("success", "Cliente Pessoa Física atualizado com sucesso");
  }
```

But ideally I want a solution to use the normal way and have it not changing to localhost:8000.